# Armazenar quantos dados eu quiser em uma coluna de uma tebela em oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle, apex

Estou criando uma página no *apex* e preciso criar um gráfico com os motivos que mais causam multas, mas uma multa pode ter vários motivos. Não estou conseguindo armazenar esse motivos de forma que eu consiga gerar o gráfico

```
CREATE TABLE "MULTA"(
    "COD_MULTA" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "DATA_APLICACAO_MULTA" DATE, 
    "QNT_PARCELAS" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "VALOR" FLOAT(2), 
    "CPF" VARCHAR2(11), 
    "NOME_MOTIVO" VARCHAR2(1000), 
    PRIMARY KEY ("COD_MULTA")
    USING INDEX ENABLE
)

CREATE TABLE "MOTIVO"(  
    "COD_MOTIVO" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "NOME_MOTIVO" VARCHAR2(1000), 
    PRIMARY KEY ("COD_MOTIVO")
    USING INDEX ENABLE
)
```

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Explique "não estou conseguindo armazenar esse motivos" , numa analise rápida o modelo deveria ser MULTA----<MOTIVO_MULTA-----MOTIVO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se uma multa pode ter mais do que um motivo então a relação entre a multas e motivos é de 1-N. Dessa forma é necessário uma terceira tabela que relacione cada multa com os seus vários motivos.

Algo deste género:

```
CREATE TABLE motivos_multa (
  COD_MULTA NUMBER,
  COD_MOTIVO NUMBER
);
```

Não inclui intencionalmente as referências às chaves estrageiras. Esta tabela tem de ser populada sempre que uma multa é inserida, associando a multa aos seus motivos (uma linha por cada motivo associado).

Para obter o motivo de multas mais frequentes a query em baixo é suficiente:

```
SELECT motivo.NOME_MOTIVO, count(1)
FROM motivos_multa 
  INNER JOIN motivo ON motivos_multa.cod_motivo = motivo.cod_motivo
GROUP BY motivo.NOME_MOTIVO;
```